# How to pass data from C# to Bartender2016

Tags: c#, bartender

I read the Bartender SDK,and write the follow code to test label template.

```
var lb = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\线标.btw";
        using (Engine engine = new Engine(true))
        {
            LabelFormatDocument btformate = engine.Documents.Open(lb);
            btformate.SubStrings["version"].Value = txtVersion.Text;
            btformate.SubStrings["pn"].Value = txtPN.Text;
            btformate.SubStrings["sn"].Value = txtsn.Text;
            btformate.SubStrings["week"].Value = txtWeek.Text;

            btformate.PrinterCodeTemplate.Performance.AllowSerialization = false;
            btformate.ExportImageToClipboard(Seagull.BarTender.Print.ColorDepth.ColorDepth256, new Resolution(200));
            engine.Stop();
        }
```

In the label template, I use Printer Code Template Field to pass data from c# to Bartender engine.

For example , I set pn = "04130032" and consider that the output will be the right string "04130032",unfortunately, Bartender display another way "4,130,032.00". As you see, it was regarded as number,I really want it to be STRING!!

#### Bartender template picture

[image]

#### template output picture

[image]

Howa can I adjust the label template and find the right way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: anyone can help? T^T

Answer (score 0):

After trying to recreate your scenario in my Bartender Software, I come out with a few things you can try:

1. Check if there is any `VBScript` in the `Barcode Human Readable` which will translate data to number
   [image]
2. Try to recreate a new BTW Template